# Adding another view on click of button in recycler view

Tags: java, android

How can we show the view on click of plus button in the below image.As I am new to android,can anyone help me out of this?

[image]

Comment: If your views are static then you can make visibility hide or show in a particular item of recycler view on click of plus button .

Comment: try using expandable view in your recycler adapter

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is enough just to add a new element in your `ArrayList` that holds all the other elements of the recycler view.